# Recursion - Flood Fill Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, fill, flood-fill

I need to write a flood fill algorithm to be used in a larger code that fills specific cells of a cave with different colors of water based on which room they are in.

For some reason my recursive algorithm isn't working and keeps telling me I'm exceeding the maximum recursion depth, and I have no clue why.

I'm trying to go cell by cell, checking if it is AIR, STONE, or WATER, and if it is STONE or WATER I want it to do nothing. If it is AIR, I want it to fill that cell.

Can anyone give me some tips or advice?

```
#flood fill algorithm
def fill(cave, row, col, color):

    caveWidth = len(cave)
    caveHeigth = len(cave[0])


    if row > 0:
        fill(cave, row-1, col, color) #left
    if col > 0:
        fill(cave, row, col-1, color) #up
    if row < caveWidth-1:
        fill(cave, row+1, col, color) #right
    if col < caveHeigth-1:
        fill(cave, row, col+1, color) #down

    if cave[row][col] == STONE or cave[row][col] == WATER:
        return

    if cave[row][col] == AIR : 
        cave[row][col] = WATER
        grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)
```

Comment: This really is best done iteratively rather than recursively. It'd be faster and more efficient

Comment: @jozefg: Isn't it rather difficult to implement a correct *fast* flood fill algorithm?

Comment: Are row and col signed or unsigned?

Comment: @user946850 true... Though a breadth first search version is far more space efficient and avoids recursion as well. Simply using a Queue instead of the call stack

Answer (score 5):

Print `row` and `col` at the start of the `fill` routine to see what's wrong here. A little code reordering and you're fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursive algorithms, they are the devil's playthings.

The wikipedia lists various practical algorithms like scanline fill.

Comment: Recursion is a perfectly useful tool for many practical problems.  Even scanline fill is typically implemented as a recursive solution, using an explicit stack instead of the thread's stack.

Comment: @TylerDurden: So what are functional languages then? Incarnations of the Evil? ;-)